# read an excel file using python when file is already open (Win32Com.client )

Tags: python

I am trying to read a excel sheet using Win32com.client

```
import Win32com.client as win32
excel=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
filename='AssetList.xls'
book=excel.WorkBooks.Open(filename)
```

Throwing Error and saying file is already open.Cannot open two documents with the same name
pywintypes.com_error:()

Please suggest a method to overcome this situation .If someone open my excel sheet the script wont work.

Comment: You mean that excel file is shared?